# Drawing text with Slick

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick

I've been trying to draw a text to the display using **Slick**.
However, when ever I draw the `TrueTypeFont` to the screen, it draws it reversed upside down and also, it makes the whole display turn black.

This is only a piece of the entire game code, I think this is enough to explain the problem though. I'm new to LWJGL and Slick so this is probably a stupid question.

```
public Game(String name, int width, int height)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;


    try {
        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
        Display.setTitle(name + " " + version);
        Display.setResizable(true);

        Display.create();
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        Display.destroy();
        return;
    }

    TrueTypeFont font;
    Font awtFont = new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24);
    font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, false);

    Player player = new Player(this, 32, 32);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    while(!Display.isCloseRequested())
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        drawBackground();

        player.update();
        player.draw();
        font.drawString(50, 50, "Platform");

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }

    Display.destroy();
}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
After doing what @Katu said, I changed `glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);` to `glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);`.
The text is not reversed upside down, but the black screen is still there.

[image]

The screen should look something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT9cf.png). (**NOTE:** It's an edited image)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, -1, 1);
```

To this:

```
glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, -1, 1);
```

> A quick little understanding about why your font wasn't working (if you don't already know), glOrtho is called like this:

```
glOrtho(double left, double right, double bottom, double top, double zNear, double zFar).
```

> This being said, you had the bottom set to 0 where it should have been set to the display's height or a custom bottom if necessary and that is the reason why the text was facing the top of the screen or rather, being drawn up-side down.

I collected this answer from these:

- [This question has been answered at stackoverflow1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11800307/1064431)
- [This question has been answered at stackoverflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13705240/1064431)

Comment: Thanks, that solved the main problem. Now it's showing a black screen with a text saying "Platform" when it's suppose to draw the player, the background, and the text. [Here's a screenshot.](http://i.imgur.com/ubV2rfi.png)

Comment: @VicenteBermúdez Test if this helps -> glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); ( Add it to near glEnable(GL_BLEND); )

Comment: I tried that and it's still remains the same. It should look something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/wzUhgWo.png)

Comment: @VicenteBermúdez Then try `glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D,0)` If this wont work, I'm out of bullets

Comment: That makes it draw a *white rectangle* instead of a *text*. The background and player is working now but the text isn't. Thanks though :)

Comment: @VicenteBermúdez add this after rendering the text?  glDisable(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D); Try to play around with these stuff (GL_TEXTURE and GL_BLEND ), you are so close, don't give up! This is great chance to learn something :)